# Is that plagiarism by Community♦?

Tags: support, plagiarism, community-user, tag-excerpt

I found this tag edit from Sep 2, 2010 by Community♦: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/3625313/revisions

It is identical to a paragraph from Feb 9, 2010 from blogspot:
https://googlesystem.blogspot.com/2010/02/google-buzz.html

Itself from an older than May 4, 2010 help article:
https://web.archive.org/web/20100528202230/http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=171454

- How come the attribution is **Community♦**?
- Is it plagiarism/copyvio?
- Who to blame?
- Shall we revert those tag-wiki-excerpt contributions from Community♦ to an empty excerpt or shall we change the format of this excerpt to a quote with linked attribution to mail.google.com?

Comment: Not sure how you got that link.. but clicking on history link in the wiki section gives [this](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/3609814/revisions)

Comment: @suraj I'm talking about the tag-wiki **excerpt**, and as such the **excerpt history** at the bottom of https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-buzz/info

Comment: Oh, but I see your point, @suraj: the edit from Bob Aman three days before Community♦ got the same initial content and copyright violation. So _Community♦_ probably took its excerpt from the tag-wiki post itself.

Comment: It's an excerpt, you can't use linking or quoting. Just put a proper excerpt there that isn't copied.

Comment: @Cœur: Interesting; that's not a feature I've seen before. I suspect that was a one-off action when excerpts were made required?

Comment: @MartijnPieters rewriting all the plagiarisms of tags would be ideal. But as it's an Herculean work to do, what are the easier doable actions? Deleting the excerpt maybe?

Comment: @Cœur: we can't delete the excerpt, it's required once a tag wiki exists.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The excerpt was copied from the first 'paragraph' in the tag wiki body. The plagiarism was introduced there in [August 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/3609814/revisions), by https://stackoverflow.com/users/90723/bob-aman.

The copy was almost certainly created as a one-off batch process when excerpts were made mandatory with a tag wiki. The whole tag wiki feature was still new (introduced in July 2010) and by September were still [actively being updated](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63192/can-we-have-an-option-to-hide-the-excerpt-from-the-full-tag-wiki-entry). At any rate, Community is never going to create copy out of thin air; the Community account is just the standard user to assign automated processes to.

Because excerpts are now mandatory when you have a tag wiki, we can't delete the excerpt. Nor can you use markup in an excerpt (it is rendered as plain text), so you can't add quoting and attribution. Nor does it make sense there.

We'll just have to replace the text with something that isn't plagiarised. Do edit the tag wiki itself *too*; there quoting and a link are appropriate.

Comment: It seems harsh to call this "plagiarism". If you look at @bob-aman's bio, it says he's an ex-Googler, and Buzz is a Google product. I would assume that this tag wiki was created while he was still at Google

Comment: @HongOoi fair enough, but then the edit description should have been explicit regarding the legitimate content (source/attribution?) instead of "_added 478 characters in body_".